# Convert calendar date to julian date - python

Tags: python, julian-date

I am trying to convert calendar date like so: `'2018-08-07'` to julian calendar day like so `'219'`. I have tried for a long time and seem to run out of ideas.
The julian day calendar is this one I am using:
https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/browse/calendar.html

This is what I have so far:

```
from datetime import date
import datetime
from PyAstronomy import pyasl

df = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 7, 12)
print(df)
jul = pyasl.jdcnv(df)
print(jul)
```

Comment: pyasl.jdcnv is for use with true Julian dates, as used by astronomers. Unfortunately this term is also used in commerce to mean the day of the year, which is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strftime` for this (see [this](http://strftime.org/) for a description of directives to use):

```
jul = df.strftime('%j')
>>> jul
'219'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def date_2_julian_string (date):
    return str(date.strftime('%y')) + date.strftime('%j')
```

Comment: What's the benefit to this articulation compared to [@sacuL's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107419/3025856) from three years ago?

Comment: benefit is the complete of julian date format: str(date.strftime('%y')) +

Comment: the former answer and you are not familiar with julian date

Comment: That just reiterates the code. Can you explain, in words, _why_ `%y` might be preferable to `%j`? You should assume that future readers won't understand the distinction, and will benefit from additional explanation.

Comment: Nobody is saying %y might be preferable to %j. Please make sure you actually read (run it if you cannot read) the code before wasting others' time.

Comment: I don't have a dog in this fight. I came across this post via the community review queues, and am (unsuccessfully) prompting you to improve your answer by providing more explanation. Answers with explanations are more useful to the community, and tend to be rewarded with more upvotes over time. That's especially true when there's a similar accepted answer.