# How do you covert normal dates (dd-mm-yyyy) into Julian dates in a dataframe?

Tags: python, date, julian-date

I have columns in my dataframe that are of normal dates, how can I covert these normal dates dd-mm-yyyy into Julian date format.

I want the column that is currently in date form(did-mum-yyyy) to be in integers(Julian date).

Comment: Please do the [tour] and read [ask]. Try to solve it, research it first, then post a [mre] and describe your problem. You will find hundreds of questions regarding date conversion in pandas in SO - at least some of them should be able to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question: [Convert calendar date to julian date - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53107367/convert-calendar-date-to-julian-date-python)

You can get the necessary integers for the dates by subscripting:

```
day, month, year = date[:2], date[3:5], date[6:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `datetime` module and [strftime and strptime formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> day = datetime.datetime.strptime('24-01-2021', '%d-%m-%Y')
>>> print(day)
2021-01-24 00:00:00
>>> print(day.strftime('%j'))
024
```